# Existence and uniqueness for IVP with a square root

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question is from an old exam that a classmate shared with me.

**Question:**
Determine if the following IVP have a solution and if it is unique or not.

i)$$\left \{\begin{matrix}y'(s) & = & \sqrt{y(s)+s}, \\ y(0) & = & x,\end{matrix}\right .$$where $x$ is a given real number.

ii)$$\left \{\begin{matrix}y_1'(s) & = & y_1(s)y_2(s), \\ y_2'(s) & = & y_1(s)+\sqrt{s}, \\ y_1(0) & = & x_1, \\ y_2(0) & = & x_2,\end{matrix}\right .$$where $x_1,x_2$ are given real numbers.

**Ideas/Attempt:**
For i) Wolfram gives a solution using Lambert's $W$-function, and this isn't something I've been taught (or know) about yet. For ii) I know how to solve for $y_1$ as a function of $s$ and $y_2$ (integrating factor, linear diff eq, etc.), but I don't know how to prove/disprove the existence of a solution.
I'll like to solve this using Peano or Picard-Lindelöf to prove existence and uniquness if possible, but I'm confused because both theorems have as hypothesis that the function $f(s,y)$ is defined in an open neighbourhodd of the point determined by the initial conditions, in this case, $(0,\text{something})$. What should I do in this case? Is there some kind of (relatively common) trick that works for differential equations involving square roots (or derivatives squared) that I should be aware of?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regarding i, the possible issue that should jump out at you is the breakdown of the Lipschitz property at $(s,y)=(0,0)$. Intuitively it seems like there should be no problem because $y' \geq \sqrt{s}$, but I'm not sure how to polish that into a proof. In ii you can just use (local) Picard-Lindelof, no problem.

Comment: But how can I prove that the function is locally Lipschitz in $y$? If I write it like $f(s,y)=(y_1y_2,y_1+\sqrt{s})$ I end up with an inequality like $(ab-cd)^2+(a-c)^2\leq L((a-c)^2+(b-d)^2)$, for which I'm unable of finding a suitable value for $L$. I'm not sure if $f$ is differentiable wrt $y$ so I can't use that either to bound the derivatives.

Comment: All norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are equivalent, so you can pick the max norm. Now $\| (y_1 y_2,y_1+\sqrt{s})-(z_1 z_2,z_1 + \sqrt{s}) \|_\infty = \| (y_1 y_2 - z_1 z_2,y_1 - z_1) \|_\infty \leq \max \{ 1,|y_2|,|z_2| \} \| y-z \|_\infty$.